# PWA 2013 - "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-project

Suddenly my PWA 2013 started showing the error below (extracted from Event Viewer)

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 11/25/2013 12:37:05 PM 
Event time (UTC): 11/25/2013 2:37:05 PM 
Event ID: 347fe626e1274a4a96fb2afc7e537b44 
Event sequence: 194 
Event occurrence: 193 
Event detail code: 0 

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT/bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6-1-130298629694620451 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: /bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6 
    Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\Shared\ProjectServer\ 
    Machine name: XXXX

Process information: 
    Process ID: 6040 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 

Exception information: 
    Exception type: ArgumentException 
    Exception message: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://XXXX:32843/bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc 
    Request path: /bea8a2b7b12941f1bc7b6a7ea02f25b6/PSI/psiserviceapp.svc 
    User host address: ::1 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 16 
    Thread account name: XXXX\svc.sharepoint.app 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar)
```

I've been searching for some clue about it but wasn't able to find anything really close to my problem. 
Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix for it.
It was a problem with the User Profile Service Application. I just managed to start it correctly and the problem is now gone.